# unhiding a div not properly working

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to unhide a div when hovering to a certain div altough it unhide, it only works on the last div.

here is the example. http://jsfiddle.net/yCPj2/

html

```
<div id="nav" style="margin: 0 auto; width: 500px;">
    <a href="#">
        <div id="nav1" style="width:99px; height: 50px; border-right: thin               solid black; float: left; background: red;"></div>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
        <div id="nav2" style="width:99px; height: 50px; border-right: thin solid black; float: left; background: red;"></div>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
        <div id="nav3" style="width:99px; height: 50px; border-right: thin solid black; float: left; background: red;"></div>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
        <div id="nav4" style="width:99px; height: 50px; border-right: thin solid black; float: left; background: red;"></div>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
        <div id="nav5" style="width:100px; height: 50px; float: left; background: red;"></div>
    </a>
    <div id="hidden"></div>
</div>
```

css

```
#hidden {
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    background: blue;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0.4;
    display: none;
}

a:hover + #hidden {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: what is your problem? be more clear

Comment: Is changing + to ~ works for you?
e.g. a:hover ~ #hidden {

Comment: You'd better use `#nav:hover > #hidden { display: block;}`, using the `a` instead of `#nav` will cause a little flicker when you hover on the first `a` (which is overlapped/covered by the hidden `div` when it's shown again).

Comment: ok im trying to create an animated navigation bar using javascript, first i have 5 navigation tab, i want a hidden div to show up when i hover to this 5 tabs.. but for some reason the hidden div only show on the 5th tab. @forestclown nope still the same..

Answer (score 0):

Change + to ~ in your hover instance:

```
a:hover ~ #hidden {
    display: block;
}
```

Also, try use display **inline-block**. This will determine the height of the elements.

Look at updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ArtemFitiskin/yCPj2/4/

```
#nav {
    font-size: 0;
    position: relative;
}

#nav a {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 99px; 
    height: 50px; 
    border-right: thin solid black;
    background: red;
    font-size: 14px;
}

#hidden {
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    background: blue;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0.4;
    display: none;
    top: 0;
}

#nav a:hover ~ #hidden {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you just need to change a certain code

```
a:hover ~ #hidden {
    display: block;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yCPj2/5/)

Answer (score 0):

Trigger your hover on the container div:

```
#nav:hover #hidden {display: block; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yCPj2/6/